# Xampp installation error on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, loadrunner

I have install loadrunner on windows 7 64 bit, Loadrunner use port 80,443,8080, So all ports that xampp use are used by loadrunner. After complete xampp installatio I have change al ports change port 80 for apach to 7777 and port 443 for https to 4433 after that Apach and Mysql start correctly but I can not access website because "localhost:7777/xampp/splash.php" return 404

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11

Comment: did you restart xampp after making the changes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the demo applications for the tutorial, not LoadRunner itself.